# Prove a limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I was given this function:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+x^2, & x\in\Bbb Q\\
x, & x\notin \Bbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
I first proved that it is continuous at $x=0$.

Now I need to prove that that for every $x_0 \in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ does not exist.

I know that I need to start by assuming that the limit does exist but I don't know how to reach a contradiction.

Comment: I've added a second answer with a complete argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x\ne0,$ first note that $x\ne x^2 +x,$ and then let $\varepsilon$ be half the distance between $x$ and $x^2+x.$

Suppose there is a limit $L.$ What value of $\delta$ is small enough to assure  you that if $x-\delta <w<x+\delta$ and $w\ne x$ then $L-\varepsilon < f(w) < L+\varepsilon\text{?}$ Some such values of $w$ are rational so that $f(w)$ will differ from $x+x^2$ by less than $\varepsilon;$ others are irrational so that $f(w)$ will differ from $x$ by less than $\varepsilon.$ Show that that implies that no matter what number $L$ is, they cannot both differ from $L$ by less than $\varepsilon.$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just can't formal it into the definition of the limit. I don't understand what will be the contradiction here. Also, isn't half the distance between $x$ and $x^2+x$ just half of $x^2$?

Comment: @AviAsks : It is just half of $x^2.$ Can you simultaneously be less than one mile away of two places that are two miles from each other? That's the situation here. The way you show it's impossible is the triangle inequality.

Comment: But I have nothing to say about $f(w)$ in relation to half of $x^2$. And on what expression I need to use the triangle inequality?

Comment: @AviAsks : You're saying two different quantities are at a distance of less than $\varepsilon$ from $L.$ The triangle inequality then implies they are at a distance of less than $2\varepsilon$ from each other. In this case that means the distance between $x$ and $x^2+x$ is less than $2\varepsilon. \qquad$

Comment: But you can't have $w$ as a rational and an irrational and the same time. Thus, you have $w_1$ and $w_2$, and when you use the triangle inequality you're "stuck" with nothing that leads you to contradiction (and if I do reach to $w^2 < x^2$, what is the contradiction here?)

Comment: @AviAsks : But you can make $w_1$ and $w_2$ as close to each other as you want.

Comment: @AviAsks : ok, Maybe I'll write a complete proof as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that I need to start by assuming that the limit does exist but I don't know how to reach a contradiction.

That's not necessary. It is sufficient to simply prove that the limit doesn't exist.

And the easiest way to do that is to consider a limit along rational values tending to $x_0$ and compare it with the limit along irrational values tending to $x_0$. That these are different amounts to saying that $x^2 + x \neq x$ when $x \neq 0$.

Comment: I need to show a formal solution. Your idea doesn't sound, although right, so formal.
Remember: I need to show that the limits doesn't exist, not that it's not continuous.

Comment: @AviAsks This can be made completely formal. The idea is sequential continuity: if $f$ is continuous at $x$, and $x_n \to x$, then $\lim f(x_n) \to f(x)$. Now you explicitly give two sequences whose limits differ, showing that $f$ is not continuous. How do you choose two sequences? You choose a sequence of rationals tending to $x_0$ and a sequence of irrationals tending to $x_0$.

Comment: I haven't learned about sequences. The only thing i know is that f is continuous at $0$. But if I show that it's not continuous all that it tells me is that the limits does not equal to the function at the given x, it doesn't says that its limit doesn't exist. I need to show that for every $x\ne0$ the limit does not exist (without any connection to continuity).

Comment: @AviAsks Necessarily if the limit doesn't exist, then it does not equal the function evaluated at $x$. Therefore it suffices to show that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I need to use the formal definition of limit in that question.

Comment: @AviAsks Ok. I don't intend to continue this commentary. But good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x_0\ne0$ and there is a limit:
$$
L = \lim_{x\,\to\, x_0} f(x).
$$
Let $\varepsilon = x_0^2/4.$ Then:

- There is some number $\delta_1>0$ such that for all values of $x$ between $x_0\pm\delta_1$ we have $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon.$
- There is some number $\delta_2>0$ such that for all values of $x$ between $x_0\pm\delta_2,$ we have $|(x+x^2)-(x_0+x_0^2)|<\varepsilon.$

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\varepsilon\}.$

A crucial fact is that no matter how small $\delta$ is, there are both rational and irrational numbers between $x_0\pm\delta.$ So let $x_1$ be a rational number in that interval and let $x_2$ be an irrational number in that interval.
\begin{align}
& |f(x_1)-L|< \varepsilon, \\[8pt]
\text{which means } & |(x_1+x_1^2) - L| < \varepsilon. \tag 1 \\[8pt] 
& |(x_1+x_1^2)-(x_0+x_0^2)| < \varepsilon. \tag 2 \\[8pt]
\text{The triangle } & \text{inequality applied to $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields:} \\
& |L-(x_0+x_0^2)|<2\varepsilon. \tag 3 \\[8pt]
\text{We also have } & |f(x_2)-L|< \varepsilon, \\[8pt]
\text{which means } & |x_2-L|<\varepsilon. \tag 4 \\[8pt]
\text{And we have } & |x_0-x_2| < \delta\le\varepsilon. \tag 5 \\[8pt]
\text{The triangle } & \text{inequality applied to $(4)$ and $(5)$ yields:} \\
& |x_0-L|<2\varepsilon. \tag 6 \\[8pt]
\text{Now the triangle } & \text{inequality applied to $(3)$ and $(6)$ gives us:} \\
& |x_0 - (x_0+x_0^2)|<4\varepsilon. \\[10pt]
\text{So } & x_0^2 < 4\varepsilon \\
\text{and we have } & \text{a contradiction.} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists, then for any sequence of numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ converging to $x_0$, we must have that $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots$ converges to $f(x_0)$. In particular we can consider two sequences converging to $x_0$: the first uses only rational numbers, and the second uses only irrational numbers. (This is possible since both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ are [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Properties).) Then, since both the function $x\mapsto x^2+x$ and the identity function are continuous, the limit of the rational sequence will be $x_0^2+x_0$ and that of the irrational sequence will be $x_0$. However if $x_0\not=0$ these quantities differ, forming a contradiction.